# Typo3 Fluid implement different frontend layouts

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid

I need different Frontend Layouts in my Typo3 Backend.
So I have created new html files in

```
template\Resources\Private\Layouts\Page
```

So beside Default.html, there is now Layout1.html and Layout2.html

After that I tried to declare those files in my setup.typoscript

```
[globalVar = TSFE:page | layout=1]
page.10.template.file = FILE:EXT:template/Resources/Private/Layouts/Page/Layout1.html
[global]

[globalVar = TSFE:Page | layout=2]
page.10.template.file = FILE:EXT:template/Resources/Private/Layouts/Page/Layout2.html
[global]
```

When I switch the frontend layout from default to layout1 or layout2 nothing changes in my frontend.

What is missing, or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does your layout names are Layout1.html and Layout2.html OR Header.html and Footer.html?

Comment: sorry, its usually Header and Footer, i just renamed to layout1/2 as example

Comment: Have you changes the layout=1 and layout=2 in backend pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

multiple aspects why you should not work in this way:

1. prefer `.templateName` instead of `.template.file`
   it is more flexible as you can have multiple outputs (`.html`, `.xml`, `.json`, ...)
2. the `layout` field is by default not inherited.
   you need to define the field value for each page
3. TS-conditions result in multiple cached versions of the typoscript
4. the backend does not represent the frontend layout for your editors

**Alternative:**

use the fields `backend_layout` and `backend_layout_next_level` like this:

```
    templateName = TEXT
    templateName.cObject = CASE
    templateName.cObject {
        key.data = levelfield:-1, backend_layout_next_level, slide
        key.override.field = backend_layout

        #Default Template
        default = TEXT
        default.value = Default

        pagets__startpage = TEXT
        pagets__startpage.value = Startpage

        pagets__simple = TEXT
        pagets__simple.value = Simple

    }
```

or you use the value direct:

```
templateName = TEXT
templateName {
    value = default
    override.cObject = TEXT
    override.cObject {
        data = levelfield:-1, backend_layout_next_level, slide
        override.field = backend_layout
    }
}
```

The backend layouts are defines in page TSconfig (deployable from `EXT:my_site_ext/Configuration/TSconfig/page.tsconfig`)

```
## define backend-layouts
mod.web_layout.BackendLayouts {
    startpage {
        title = Startpage Layout
        config {
            backend_layout {
                colCount = 4
                rowCount = 4
                rows {
                     :
                }
            }
        }
    }
    simple {
        title = Simple Layout
        config {
            backend_layout {
                colCount = 2
                rowCount = 2
                rows {
                     :
                }
            }
        }
    }
    default {
        title = Default Layout
        config {
            backend_layout {
                colCount = 4
                rowCount = 3
                rows {
                     :
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

if you want the `layout` field to adapt the general frontend template you need to transfer this information into the fluid-template:

```
variables {
    :
    layout = TEXT
    layout.field = layout
    :
}
```

Then you can consider the layout in your template (or layout) files:

```
<f:if condition="{layout} == 1">
    <then><f:render partial="header1" /></then>
    <else><f:if condition="{layout} == 2">
        <then><f:render partial="header2" /></then>
        <else><f:render partial="header0" /></else></fi>
    </else>
</fi>
```

and also here you can use the value immediatly (be sure to have all partials available):

```
<f:render partial="header{layout}" />
```

---

In general you can use these two fields in multiple ways, here some other usages:

typoscript:

```
page.10.template {
    templateName = Default

    variables {
        beLayout = TEXT
        beLayout.data = levelfield:-1, backend_layout_next_level, slide
        beLayout.override.field = backend_layout

        feLayout = TEXT
        feLayout.field = layout

        :
    }
}
```

**1.**

you use a static template, and the BE- and FE-layout fields are fluid variables which decide further rendering in fluid:

in Templates/Default.html:

```
<html xmlns:f="http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/CMS/Fluid/ViewHelpers"
  data-namespace-typo3-fluid="true">
<f:layout name="{beLayout}" />

<f:section name="Main">
    <f:if condition="{feLayout} == 1">
          <div class="col-visual">{content_visual->f:format.raw()}</div>
    </f:if>

    <div class="col-main">{content_main->f:format.raw()}</div>

    <f:if condition="{feLayout} == 2">
         <div class="col-infobox">{content_infobox->f:format.raw()}</div>
    </f:if>
</f:section>
```

**2.**

in Templates/Default.html:

```
<f:render partial="{beLayout}" section="{feLayout}" arguments="{_all}" />
```

**3.**

in Templates/Default.html:

Comment: i dont want to change my backendlayouts, but the frontendlayouts. so the files in the layout and not template folder

Comment: if you already have backendlayouts attach the frontendlayouts to the backend-layouts

Comment: can't backend layouts dynamically use frontend layouts?

Comment: in general backend layouts and frontend layouts are independent. But for editors it was complicated when the TYPO3 BE layout was 6 columns side by side and the FE rendered them in a mosaik (1 col full width, 3 col, width 1:4:1, where the third column consists of two of the BE columns above each other, and finaly one footer column full with). For representing such a layout the BE layouts were introduced in TYPO3 (one of the old 4 versions)

Comment: So when i choose Frontendlayout Layout1 and Backendlayout Example1 in the page settings, only party in the section <f:layout name="Example1" /> will be shown?

Comment: in my logic it will use a template "Example1" and there a partial "Layout1" is selected. As you can have variables you can build your own fluid-logic including Fluid-layouts, -templates, -partials. It primarily depends on the wording what field will be used for what feature. (I'll append my answer)

Answer (score 0):

The safe ways:

- Have multiple `Layout` files located next to each other
- Name alternative layouts with *suffixes*, e.g. `MyLayoutSpecial.html` as alternative to `MyLayout.html`
- Assign a template variable that contains the "type" of `Layout` to use and have that variable contain either nothing or a string like `Special`
- In the template, use `<f:layout name="MyLayout{layoutType}" />` to refer to your layout

The result is a safe resolving of layout files, assuming you check the values always correspond to a physical layout file. If you don't assign `{layoutType}` your layout name is `MyLayout` and if you assign it with a value of `Special` your layout name is `MyLayoutSpecial`.

Please note that you cannot have multiple `f:layout` in the same template as only the first will be used. The only way to give multiple possible layout options is to make the `name` property value dynamic, for example with a simple variable as part of the name.

Second option - template wrapping and `contentAs`:

Fluid also allows you to render a section for example from a partial template, but pass a variable that you can fill by using tag contents of `f:render`. This causes the rendered tag content to be passed as a variable that you can then wrap.

Combining this with dynamic partial names or dynamic section names (see above for how to make that safe) means you can refer to any type of dynamic wrapping without having a huge set of conditions. For example:

```
<!-- In the template that renders the partial -->
<f:render partial="Wrap{specialWrap}" arguments="{_all}" contentAs="content">
    <div>The thing that needs to be wrapped with dynamic wrapping</div>
</f:render>

<!-- In the partial template, for example called `WrapDiv.html` -->
<div class="foo">
    <f:format.raw>{content}</f:format.raw>
</div>
```

Comment: i dont get the point how this would help with changing the frontend layouts? this looks like something different than what I need

Comment: It's about trying to get you to think differently about "changing layout" - to encourage you to encapsulate that layout (wrapping) selection in Fluid. Though you may not need to do so right now, I assure you that depending on a single template variable (which you can build with TS!) is a lot more future proof than dynamically selecting different template files for the FLUIDTEMPLATE cObject based on various dynamic stuff.